# All object properties have different keys but are of the same type

Tags: typescript, object

I have an object, used only once, with just three properties but each property should be of the same type. The following works for me but I wonder if there is a more efficient way of declaring the type for `timingsObject`:

```
  let timingsObject:
     { start: null | string, end: null | string, length: null | string } =
     { start: null, end: null, length: null }

  // ... later on timeingsArray is of string[] type
  timingsObject.start = timingsArray[0];
  timingsObject.end = timingsArray[1];
  timingsObject.length = timingsArray[2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bad**

You *could* define your shape as

```
interface Timings {
  start: string | null;
  end: string | null;
  length: string | null;
}
```

but this design fails to express your problem properly. For example, `{ start: string, end: null, length: null }` is correct on the type level, but represents an invalid state in your program.

If we were to do:

```
if (timingsObject.start) {
  typeof timingsObject.length.toString(); // Compile-type error!
}
```

we know `timingsObject.length` is a string, but TypeScript doesn't. Before any other property of `timingsObject` can be used, it needs to be validated to be a `string` first.

**Good**

Model your problem as a sum of two states. The first one is well-defined:

```
interface Timings {
    start: string;
    end: string;
    length: string;
}
```

the second one is its empty equivalent. Your input is either one or another, which can be expressed as:

```
declare const timings: Empty<Timings> | Timings;
```

How do we model `Empty`? Let's make it a mapped type that turns everything into `null`.

```
type Empty<T> =
  T extends object
    ? { [K in keyof T]: null }
    : null

declare function isEmpty<T>(argument: T | Empty<T>): argument is Empty<T>;
```

Now the compiler knows that if one property is a string, then every other property is a string as well.

```
if (!isEmpty(timings)) {
  timings.start + timings.end; // Both are known to be strings!
}
```

This solution might look like wore work (and it is), but it succeeds at baking your domain problem into the type system.

Comment: Good consideration of possible / allowed states. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two alternative ways of doing this. A generic type or a predefined type.

```
interface IObject<T> {
  start: T
  end: T
  length: T
}

type myType = string | null

interface IObject2 {
  start: myType
  end: myType
  length: myType
}

let timingsObject: IObject<string | null> = { start: null, end: null, length: null }
let timingsObject: IObject2 = { start: null, end: null, length: null }
```

Comment: I added an example of how you would initialize the `timingsObject` using the above types

Answer (score 0):

Since all the properties of a timings object will either all be a string, or all be falsy (and actually not used in this state), and since all the properties are applied in just one place we can also:

```
interface Timings {
    start: string;
    end: string;
    length: string;
}

let timings?: Timings; // could also use let timings: Timings | null = null;

// do other things ...

timings = {
    start: "someValue",
    end: "someOtherValue,
    length: "yetAnotherValue"
};
```